# In Express, should I validate data directly in the request body, or store it in res.locals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can think of two ways to maniuplate user inputs in Express (e.g. trimming strings).

The first is to maniuplate the data directly inside the body object in the request (i.e. req.body). The second is to store the data in res.locals. Here's an example of both cases.

**Trimming spaces in req.body**

```js
app.post("/contacts/new",
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.errorMessages = [];
    next();
  },
  (req, res, next) => {
    for (let inputName in req.body) {
      req.body[inputName] = req.body[inputName].trim();
    }
    next();
  },
```

**Storing results in res.locals**

```js
app.post("/contacts/new",
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.errorMessages = [];
    next();
  },
  (req, res, next) => { // trim whitespace
    res.locals.firstName   = req.body.firstName.trim();
    res.locals.lastName    = req.body.lastName.trim();
    res.locals.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber.trim();
    next();
  },
```

What are the pros and cons of both methods? Is there a best practice here?

Comment: Just for what it's worth, neither of those shows any *validation*. Some data prep (trimming), but not validation. Did you mean to do checks on the trimmed strings, or...?

Comment: Yeah, I misspoke. I just meant "manipulating user data" in general. In this case, it's trimming. Updated the question.